# border change on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a thumbnail page where the image borders change upon hover.  The code is working to add the black borders to all the images, but only the borders for the images in the bottom 3 lines seem to change upon hover.  I have looked over the  code and do not see the difference/change between the top rows and the bottom ones. I am not sure what is going wrong?

```html
<table class="tableThumbnails" border="0" cellspacing="14%" cellpadding="14%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/AquinnahCliffs.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/AddNothingEvil.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/CircleOfBirches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage1.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Docks.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage2.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage3.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage4.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/marthasVineyardPath.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage5.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/RiverFarm.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage6.png" max-width="177" alt="" /> </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Sparkle.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage7.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/collage8.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/ComeTrue.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/DakotaAndDylan.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/destination.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/family.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/flowerPetals.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/FortuneCookies.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/grounded.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/InquireWithin.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/ItsTheEndOfTheLineSomewhere.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/LetEaglesFly.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/lifejackets.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/NakedontheFloor.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/nowShowing.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/OftheMother.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/pilgrimage.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/PintheBlastontheDeathStar.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/Pouquat.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/Ripple.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/saveMe.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/SeeYaLaterAlligator.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/theDream.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/theFireinmyHeart.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/Torch.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="galleries/collageThumbnail/Treasure.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add your css please

Comment: Could you please add your CSS code?

Comment: also it will be better if you added online images for the snippet so we can recreate your issue and configure it

Comment: add your css code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6mddfmjr/1/ works fine. Can't see your error without your CSS

Answer (score 0):

```css
img:hover
{
border:3px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table class="tableThumbnails" border="0" cellspacing="14%" cellpadding="14%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/AquinnahCliffs.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/CircleOfBirches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Docks.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/marthasVineyardPath.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/RiverFarm.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /> </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Sparkle.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/4112/Clue_Simple_Clouds.png" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this one.
I just added a transparent border for all elements, to make the images size the same on hover.

```css
a img {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

a img:hover {
    border: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table class="tableThumbnails" border="0" cellspacing="14%" cellpadding="14%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/AquinnahCliffs.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/CircleOfBirches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Docks.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/ocean.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/marthasVineyardPath.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/RiverFarm.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /> </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/Sparkle.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/StoneCross.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpgg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/lakeTahoe.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="thumbnails">
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/waterfall.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/birches.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="landscape/dardanelles.html" title="click for larger image"><img src="https://ftssum18.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/tint1.jpg" max-width="177" alt="" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```